# How to refer to the google map object in reactjs (not the component) to use getCenter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with google maps in reactjs, i need to pass the reference of the google map object, in order to send it in a function and further apply the functions associated with it. Basically i want to use the getCenter() method on the map object.. Refer this link: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

This is my map component from which i want the reference of my mapObject.

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(

withProps({
googleMapURL:
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=iDl- 
  mPD1j0K6lTEiMhs3D8axW53U&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
  loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
  mapElement: <div id="mapid" style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),

  lifecycle({
  componentWillMount() {
  console.log("Method called");
  const refs = {}

  this.setState({
    bounds: null,
    center: {
      lat: 0, lng: 0
    },


    })
   },
 }),

withScriptjs,
withGoogleMap
)(props => (

<GoogleMap  defaultZoom={15} defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng 
}} onCenterChanged={props.onChange(googlemapobjectref)}>
 {props.isMarkerShown && (
  <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />
  )}
</GoogleMap>
));
```

And in the App component (Parent Component) I want to use reference of the map object in the onChange() function.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
 super(props);

 this.state=
   {
    ....
   };


   this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    }


 onChange(googlemapobjectref){
   const val = googlemapobjectref.getCenter();
}
```

I just want to use getCenter() method in this code. If i am wrong at some point plz mention and if anything is not clear, mention that too. I will try to make it clear. Thanx in advance